# Can't see formulas

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I'm using chrome on linux and I can't see the latex equations. Does anybody also notice that?

Comment: I don't have any issues with chrome on linux...

Comment: could you provide more details about your platform (flavor of linux, version of chrome etc)

Comment: MathJax is taking much, much longer for me to render mathematics than the previous system did (upwards of 20s).  How long are you waiting before giving up?

Comment: # uname -a
Linux top-laptop 2.6.32-24-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 5 09:20:59 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 7.0.509.0 Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: MathJax works pretty quickly for me (firefox on ubuntu/windows)

Answer (score 5):

I seem to have the same problem now. According to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54981 the problem was introduced around 28 Aug. You were probably using the dev version, right? Anyway, there's also a bug filed against MathJax http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3062770&group_id=261188&atid=1240827

For now, you may want to go to google's bug (first link) and vote for it (see star to the left of 54981) so that we bump the priority of the problem.

Comment: I justed voted this bug in the tracker. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a beta version of Chrome, know that we do not support ANY beta browsers by policy. It's difficult enough supporting the quirks of all the released browsers without adding more beta insanity to the mix.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://www.mathjax.org/demos/ ?

Answer (score 1):

What are you seeing exactly? Do you see empty space, or do you see something like *[Math Processing Error]*?

I was having issues with the latter, and clearing my browser's cache fixed the problem.

Comment: I had that problem as well, but on the math.SE site. I should also try clearing my cache

Comment: Clearing the cache didn't help. I see empty space, but also some math symbols randomly placed all over the page. My guess is it's a positioning bug. See for example http://imgur.com/kRsn1.jpg

Comment: you'll probably need to ping the mathJax folks.